# Implement two different Operation on the same Column in a query using SQL

Tags: sql

I am a SQL beginner programmer and I want to write an SQL code which should count the number of entries in a column in two different ways. Like first just count them and then count only those values which are greater than 5.

I am using the following code but it is giving error.

```
SELECT
    table1.col1,
    Count(table1.col1) AS Expr1,
    count (where(table1.col1)>5) as expr2
FROM table1
GROUP BY tabl1.col1
```

the error is about the where expression used in : `count (where(table1.col1)>5) as expr2.`

Is there anyother sql function which i can use to filter out values greater than 5 before counting..

Thank you.

Comment: Use `SUM` with `CASE...END`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    col1,
    count(col1) as Expr1,
    sum(case when col1 > 5 then 1 else 0 end) as expr2
from table1
group by col1
```

or

```
select
    col1,
    count(col1) as Expr1,
    count(case when col1 > 5 then col1 end) as expr2
from table1
group by col1
```

First one just add 1 for each `col1 > 5`. Second one counts all not null values of expression  `case when col1 > 5 then col1 end`, which equals `col1` if `col1 > 5` otherwise equals `null`

Answer (score 2):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT table1.col1,
       Count(table1.col1) AS Expr1,
       SUM(case when table1.col1 > 5 then 1 else 0 end) as expr2
FROM table1
GROUP BY table1.col1;
```

Some versions of SQL treat booleans as the integer values `0` and `1`.  For these, you can simplify the expression to:

```
SELECT t1.col1,
       Count(t1.col1) AS Expr1,
       SUM(t1.col1 > 5) as expr2
FROM table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.col1;
```

This version also introduces table aliases.  This makes the query more readable and fixes the typo in the `order by` clause.

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon Linoff for answering the question. I have tried this code in MS Access Query SQL (as i don't have any other SQL programme right now) but it is not working.. It is giving missing operator error.

Comment: Thank you Gordon , I have solve the issue. Now instead of case I am using switch statement since MS Access supports Switch.. Thanks a lot for helping me..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT table1.col1,
       SUM(case when table1.col1 > 5 then 1 else 0 end) as expr2,
       Count(table1.col1) AS Expr1 
FROM table1
GROUP BY tabl1.col1
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close:

```
SELECT
  col1,
  count(*) AS Expr1,
  sum(case when col1)>5 then 1 end) as expr2
FROM table1
GROUP BY col1
```